# problema conexion imap php outlook

Tags: php, outlook, imap

Tengo el siguiente problema no he logrado establecer conexión estoy usando php5 y el servidor de correo outlook 365, lo que no tengo claro es el hostname, he probado con el siguiente :

```
        $hostname = '{outlook.office365.com/tls/novalidate-cert}';
        $username = 'nombre@correo.com';
        $password = 'xxxxxxx';
        $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to outlook: ' . imap_last_error());
        $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
        if($emails) {
             $output = '';
             rsort($emails);
             foreach($emails as $email_number) {
              $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
               $output.= 'Name:  '.$overview[0]->from.'</br>';
               $output.= 'Message ID:  '.$overview[0]->message_id.'</br>';
               $output.= 'Subject:  '.$overview[0]->subject.'</br>';
               $output.= 'UID:  '.$overview[0]->uid.'</br>';
               $output.= '<hr/>';
             }
              echo $output;
          }  
          imap_close($inbox);
```

Y obtengo los siguientes errores :

> Message: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream
>   {outlook.office365.com/tls/novalidate-cert}
>
> Retrying PLAIN authentication after AUTHENTICATE failed. (errflg=1)

En la configuración de outlook me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaré atento a sus respuestas de alguien que le haya pasado algo similar saludos.

Comment: Prueba poniendo el puerto: `$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/tls/novalidate-cert}';` o bien así: `$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/notls}';`

Comment: probe lo que me mencionas y obtengo errores similares a los mencionados en la pregunta Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/notls} , Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=2) no tengo claro cual es el problema

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente a ver si te funciona

```
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/tls}'
```

o igual intenta asi

```
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}'
```